# Why is `DateTime.add(const Duration(days: 1)` adding *Seconds* instead of Days?

Tags: flutter, dart, datetime

I have a `Text()` widget that displays a `DateTime` as a `String`. This `Text()` widget is wrapped with a `GestureDetecture()` where the `onTap` should update the `DateTime` by one *day*:

```
GestureDetector(
            child: File2(
              dateTime: date,
              key: Key(date.toString()),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                // This is adding seconds not days
                date = date.add(const Duration(days: 1));
              });
            },
          ),
```

However, the date is not updating by one day although I'm doing:

```
date = date.add(const Duration(days: 1));
```

It is however updating by a few seconds. Why isn't it updating by 1 day?

**What I tried:**
Using a `Key()`

**Code:**

`file_1.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

import 'file_2.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(File1());
}

class File1 extends StatefulWidget {
  const File1({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<File1> createState() => _File1State();
}

class _File1State extends State<File1> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    DateTime date = DateTime.now();

    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: File2(
              dateTime: date,
              key: Key(date.toString()),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                // This is adding seconds not days
                date = date.add(const Duration(days: 1));
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

`file_2.dart`:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class File2 extends StatelessWidget {
  DateTime dateTime;
  File2({Key? key, required this.dateTime}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Text(dateTime.toString());
  }
}
```

- How can I update the `Text()` in `File2` by 1 day when clicking on the `GestureDetector()`?
- Do I need to use a statemanagement other then `setState()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Problem**

This error occurs simply because you have this line at the beginning of the build method: `DateTime date = DateTime.now();`.

This is the workflow of what is happening in your code:

1. You set the date value to `DateTime.now()` at the beginning of the build method.
2. This current date value is rendered in your UI.
3. You trigger the function to update your date.
4. +1 day is added to the date.
5. IMPORTANT: Step 4 triggers the rebuild of your widget, hence Step 1 is executed again.

As a result of Step 5, the date value just gets updated for a moment, but then the `DateTime.now()` is rendered in UI.

**Solution**

Initiate the `date` value in your State class and not in the build method. This way, your `date` value won't be overwritten by the Widget rebuild:

```
class _File1State extends State<File1> {
  DateTime date = DateTime.now(); // <-- Initiate the value here
  
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        body: Center(
          child: GestureDetector(
            child: File2(
              dateTime: date,
              key: Key(date.toString()),
            ),
            onTap: () {
              setState(() {
                // This is adding seconds not days
                date = date.add(const Duration(days: 1));
              });
            },
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```